# Browser BackButton after leaving Page with React's Routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, back-button

I have an single-page-application with react & react-router. Unfortunately, some pages are still not part of that singe-page-app, and are "normal websites". So I made a Fall back with within the Router to redirect to these normal links. My Fallback looks like this:

```
             <Switch>
                [...]
                <Route exact path="/my_path">
                    <MyComponent />
                </Route>
                //Fallback:
                <Route component={(props) => {
                    let location = useLocation();
                    window.location.assign(location.pathname);
                    return null;
                }}/>
            </Switch>
```

After leaving the singe-page-application, the browsers opens the link as intended.

The Problem: I can't click the Browser's back button when I am at that new page. I mean I can click it, and the url in my browser is changing, but it's not reloading the page. So in the end I'm on that "external" page, but the browser show the url of my single-page-application. How can I force the browser to reload that page to enter my single-page-application again?

Thanks in advance,
Nicolai